# Why doing wrong by many people should not make that right?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, deleted-answers, not-an-answer

Today I decided to help this community, that for many years is helping me a lot on several answers among all programming languages and tech realtive questions.

So I've read the rules and I answered a question:
[PHP SQL-Injection not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024747/php-sql-injection-not-working/48024839#48024839)

But some guys started to down vote and tell me I was wrong in answering, instead I should comment.

What the help page states for ANSWERS(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):

"Answer the question
Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. **Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful**, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

What the help page states for COMMENTS (https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):
"**When should I comment?**
You should submit a comment if you want to:

- Request clarification from the author;
- Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
- Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated)."

Then my answer (that was not the final answer but if well used could help to reach the right result) was deleted by some moderator.

So my doubt is... I followed what is said in help page (and by the rules), but some guys think their desire are better than to follow some rules. I remain thinking: "even if everybody is doing wrong, that does not make wrong thing right).

Comment: An answer has to actually *answer* the question. I agree with the down-voters as you're giving a suggestion on how to debug but it in no way truly answers the actual question. You may not have reputation enough to comment yet, but if you persevere, you soon will.

Comment: So you too mean the help page of stackoverflow is not right when they say "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful" ?

Comment: Yes, I too, and I would presume that the majority of us agree. You will want to beware of the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) where asking a question on meta about a stackoverflow question brings additional attention to the question, possibly positive attention and possibly negative attention.

Comment: @AsK They key word there being, "answer".  An *answer*.  You didn't post an answer.  You posted a clarifying question an in no way even attempted to answer the question, even incompletely.

Comment: Please don't give up or be discouraged as it takes a bit to get used to answering on this site, but you likely have much to contribute, so again, please persevere.

Comment: Consider for a moment if this site would have helped you as much as it has if we *didn't* have those rules in place. Also do keep in mind that we're not only answering questions here to help the original asker, but to help everyone else who comes across the question in the future. There's nothing concrete in that answer, it's just a general hint on debugging and something we kind of expect the people who ask to have done already.

Comment: I understand you guys, but the point is the rules don't say I must provide full answer. I copied the fragment that says anything that gets the asker to the right direction should be an "answer"... this is written in the help page, it is not my own thinking.

Comment: But I think  I get the point... As answer I should have the full solution (maybe this should be better name in place of answer). What I was trying was to help the asker to better understand where the problem should be...   that makes sense for me.

Comment: The help page could probably have been worded better, but be that as it may, there are no rules for when to up or down-vote. If someone does not think an answer is useful they're free to downvote it. In this case I suspect that's what happened. If you look at most other answers that are posted (and especially those that are upvoted), they contain information on how to solve the problem, not on how to debug them. Like the eel spaceship said, don't be disheartened but keep that in mind. Also, don't worry about downvotes here on meta, they don't really mean much.

Comment: Thanks @ivarni I use this site for many years but almost always not logged in. As this time of year there's no customers bottering I decided to use some time to contribute. Maybe I am not prepared for contributing yet... I am now developing for about 21 years, maybe the next 21 I can learn how to deal with what I think is not right. :)

Comment: FYI:  no diamond moderators were involved in this.  This post was deleted from a review queue.

Comment: I am learning better now. But I don't know yet about review and moderators ;)  Thanks @Makoto

Comment: A diamond moderator (me) was involved here, but only to delete the comments on that answer. Those comments were over the line and were directly insulting to AsK, which is why they were removed. I'm sorry you had to deal with that, and I'm sure that was a factor in asking this question. There are plenty of constructive ways of telling you that an answer could be fleshed out, and you being told to "stop acting like a child" was not one of them.

Answer (score 18):

Right, so here's the problem:  **your answer was a comment.**

Effectively, your answer could have been better served if it were a comment, since it was telling the OP to add debug output to their code so that they could better figure out what was going on.

This reads clearer with the original post in context:

> Why don't you put an...
>
> echo ($sql2);
>
> ...right after your query concatenation, so you could easly see how is the end string that is passing to DB server? Or even copy and paste this SQL output onto DB server for checking the exact error?

This isn't answering the question; this is commenting to the effect of, "Hey, try this thing and see what output you get.  Then we can finish fixing the problem."

The point of answers is that they should actually *answer* or attempt to answer the question.  You're not doing so here, so it's no surprise that your answer was deleted from review.

For more context, check out [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: I understand your point, I agree with that. But I think it should be better if with begginer's reputation I could comment and not to answer. When developers gave permissions for answering before permissions for commenting, it seems answers are more flexible. It seems incomplete answers (or pointing to a debug) is much more harm then commenting someting that people may don't like. :)

Comment: @AsK We need a reputation threshold for commenting to prevent spammy comments. Commenting only requires 50 rep. That may seem like a lot, but really, that's only 5 up votes on an answer of yours, or 10 up votes on questions of yours. If you ask a few good questions, you can get it easy. It's just enough rep that you need to be somewhat acquainted with the site to obtain it. Yes it would be nice if commentibg was "free", but the nature of people makes that unfeasible.

Comment: @AsK: No, an incomplete answer is not an answer at all, and doesn't belong in the answer space. The heading above that text area has the heading **Your Answer** because that is exactly what it is intended to contain. You cannot use it to work around not yet having the comment privilege. It takes very little effort to earn 50 reputation points (you're almost there), and at the time you do so you can comment here, but not before. Those are the guidelines, and they exist for a specific reason. SO stays a useful resource because those rules are enforced, and you need to follow them.